# Java application not connecting to oracle database with correct username/password

Tags: java, oracle

I have spring boot application which used ojdbc6 11.2.0.3 driver. Following are my spring data source properties

```
spring.datasource.username=abc
spring.datasource.password=abc
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy= org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

This gives error `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

i'm 100% sure username/password correct. Also db has SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON=FALSE. I checked with both uppercase and lowercase username/password and still get error. Simple java app with same driver connect to db fine.

What would cause this ? What direction should i investigate. Is this could related to https://community.oracle.com/thread/2188514. My JDK is 14.0.1.

Comment: Ok, set aside your application for a moment.  Can you successfully login to the database using SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer?

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak Yes. I can login using sqlplus.

Comment: You might have to set the debugging level to `TRACE` to get a more in-depth trace of what the problem is. That is, if you're certain it isn't the credentials. The error certainly suggests the credentials are wrong. Is it possible the host is incorrect?

Comment: @Jason I checked the simple java app connecting to db using same host user and password and it success. Host is correct. Yes will check on trace level logs. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are 100% sure the password is right, perhaps you are affected by the problem in the JIT

**Connection To Database From Oracle JVM Using Server Side Jdbc Thin Driver Throws Ora-01017**

When the Java code is deployed to a pre-11g database the server-side JDBC/thin connection works fine.
After the Java code is deployed to a 11.2 database the server-side JDBC/thin connection fails with ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

You can try this workaround

```
alter system set java_jit_enabled=FALSE;
```

Comment: I have not tried this. Issue is resolved after using ojdbc8-12.1.0 driver for database version 11.2.0.4 . Previously we used  ojdbc6 11.2.0.3 driver and 11.2.0.4. Both gave above user/password error. Updating the driver resolved the issue.